# How to construct an ordered Map as a persistent data structure?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, tree, trie

I have a persistent data structure `hamt` based on a hashed array mapped trie, which is the basis for a couple of more specific persistent data structures, like an immutable array for instance. It provides a rather plain API:

```
const hamtDel = (hamt, props, k) => {/* implementation */}
const hamtGet = (hamt, k) => {/* implementation */}
const hamtSet = (hamt, props, k, v) => {/* implementation */}
const hamtEmpty = () => {/* implementation */} // creates an empty hamt
```

`hamt`, `k`, `v` are self-explanatory. `props` is just a means to add arbitrary properties to the freshly generated `hamt` object. The immutable array, for instance, has additional `length` and `offset` properties to allow efficient `cons` and `snoc` operations.

`hamt` itself is basically an unordered Map. Since ordered Maps are common in Javascript I tried to implement one based on `hamt`. However, this turns out to be quite difficult. In order to keep track of the insertion order I need a `hamt` `A` for the actual key/value pairs as well as one that holds the mapping from number-of-insertion to the corresponding key `B`.

Given both structures I can access `A`'s elements as usual and traverse `A` by retrieving the insertions order hold by `B`. However, when I want to delete an element in `A` I also need to delete it in `B`. The keys in `B` are the number-of-insertions. That means in the worst case I would have to traverse the entire `B` structure to find the corresponding key.

A third `hamt` with `B`'s key/value pairs inverted could mitigate the issue, but ending up with three `hamt`s just to obtain an ordered Map seems a poor design choice.

I am pretty sure this problem is well-known and there are solid solutions to solve it. I haven't found anything helpful yet since I lack the proper terminology. Help on this matter is very welcome.

Comment: do you have some code? and some examples?

Comment: The usual way of implementing an ordered dictionary AFAIK is to store both the unordered dict, and an array of the values in insertion order. Since you have control over the implementation, you could combine a HAMT with a persistent vector, the elements of both just point to the contained values.

Comment: @phipsgabler Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few implementations to take a look at in Scala and Kotlin.

First up is scala's `VectorMap` (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/VectorMap.scala)

It uses a combination of a Compressed Hash Array-Mapped Trie, also known as CHAMP (an immutable hashmap similar to a HAMT), together with a Vector which is a Radix Balanced Tree to store the keys in order.

Next there's scala's `TreeSeqMap` (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSeqMap.scala)

This uses the same CHAMP hashmap as VectorMap, but together with a specialized Trie-Map where keys are like integer indexes, and values are the actual keys of the ordered map.

Next there's this proposed `LinkedHashMap` that I wrote a few months ago which is very similar to a mutable double-linked-list backed LinkedHashMap, but splits the linked lists into segments to allow for better persistent updates: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8644/files

Finally there's Kotlin's `OrderedMap` here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable/blob/master/core/commonMain/src/implementations/persistentOrderedMap/PersistentOrderedMap.kt Which is basically the same thing as the previous implementation except the Link segments are all of length 1 (i.e., each key-value is its own segment or in other words there aren't segments but just individual elements which point forward and back by key instead of by pointer).